# Prove if statements are ligically equivalent

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Q)** Is (A∩B)C = (AC)∩(BC) true? If so prove it.

I think it is true just to check it out i took A={x}, B={x,y}, C={x,y,z}

So A∩B = {x}, then (A∩B)C = {(x,x),(x,y),(x,z)}

So (AC)∩(BC) = {(x,x),(x,y),(x,z)}∩{(x,x),(x,y),(x,z),(y,x),(y,y),(y,z)} = {(x,x),(x,y),(x,z)}

So for these values for A,B and C it is proven that it is true. But how do I prove it in such a way that it is true for any values for A,B and C? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $(x,y)\in (A\cap B)\times C$. Then, $x\in A,x\in B$, and $y\in C$. Hence, $(x,y)\in A\times C$ and $(x,y)\in B\times C$; i.e., $(x,y)\in (A\times C)\cap (B\times C)$. Thus, $(A\cap B)\times C\subseteq (A\times C)\cap (B\times C)$.

Conversely,  suppose $(x,y)\in(A\times C)\cap (B\times C)$. Then, $(x,y)\in A\times C$, which implies $x\in A$ and $y\in C$. But also, $(x,y)\in B\times C$, so that $x\in B$ and $y\in C$. Thus, $x\in A\cap B$ and $y\in C$. Therefore, $(x,y)\in (A\cap B)\times C$. It follows that $(A\times C)\cap (B\times C)\subseteq (A\cap B)\times C$.

Whence, by mutual inclusion, we have the desired result.